# how to chain multiple middleware together

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How can I chain 2 middleware together? I have some actions `RequestInfoAction, RequestBuildNameAction` that need to get response from api. Due to application required I need to execute `setInfo` middleware before `buildName`
my idea is pass `setInfo` as parameter to `buildName` and execute it under buildName. but it does not seem possible
so how can I chain middleware together and make them executed async?

```
//middleware
export const buildName = (action: AnyAction) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const num = getState()?.number || 0;
    dispatch(action);
  };
};



export const setInfo = (action: AnyAction) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const information = getState()?.info || {};
    dispatch(action);
  };
};

import {useDispatch}

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleOnClick = callBack(()=>{
    dispatch(setInfo(RequestBuildNameAction))
    dispatch(buildName(RequestBuildNameAction))
    //maybe something like dispatch(buildName(setInfo(RequestBuildNameAction)))
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}></button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us the simple example link

Comment: You can call setInfo and wait for it execution using async-await and after that call buildName

Comment: @NishargShah how can I do it?

Comment: using async await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleOnClick = useCallBack(async ()=>{
    await dispatch(setInfo(RequestBuildNameAction))
    await dispatch(buildName(RequestBuildNameAction))

  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises or async/await for this.

Async/await would be a better option:

```
export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleOnClick = useCallBack(async ()=>{
    await dispatch(setInfo(RequestBuildNameAction))
    dispatch(buildName(RequestBuildNameAction))
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}></button>
    </div>
  );
}
```